# Least cost algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I came across this question in a contest and couldn't think of an algorithm other than the brute force method of checking and computing the cost with every digit in the string and then outputting the least cost.

A string consisting of digits (0-9) is given and an integer `query` is given. We need to make sure that any of the digits in the string (0-9) is repeated >= `query` times. This is done by replacing individual digits in the string with another digit, and the cost of the operation is the difference between the replaced digit and the digit we are replacing with. Find the minimum cost to make sure that at least one digit exists in the string >= `query` number of times.

Is there a good algorithm for this?

Comment: At least one of the digits appears more than `x` times, or all digits?

Comment: Also, what happens if a digit doesn't appear in the string to begin with?

Comment: And what if the sum of all queries is greater than the length of given string?

Comment: So it's O(n) to count the occurrences of each digit, and O(10) to figure out which digit is the best. Overall O(n). I don't see how you could do better than that.

Comment: Either the question is too unclear to understand or @user3386109 's comment makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov at least one of the digits. If a digit doesnt appear in the string, then the number of occurences of some other digit has to increase

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the initial string - you only need the number of times each digit is met in it. Thus you can convert the string to an array of 10 ints-  the number of times each of the digits is met in the string. From there on you can use something like a brute force - for each digit X, assume that you want to have at least Q(query) X-s. Iterate over the remaining digits and greedily first convert the digits closer to X(again do that in the array of counts instead of the original string), you don't need to actually **convert** simply consider the number of times the given digit is met. This algorithm will end up with complexity in the order of O(10^3 + n) which is as good as you can get I think.